# If statement inside for loop not working

Tags: php, post, for-loop

```
for ($i=1; $i<=27 ; $i++) { 
        echo 'listid='.$i.'';
        echo 'statusid='.$_POST[$i].'';

            if (isset($_POST[$i])) {
            $listid = $i;
            $statusid = $_POST[$i];
            // $funcs->insertAudit($listid,$statusid);
        }
    }
```

Can you put a variable inside a `$_POST`? Because it seems like that is my problem. It displays this error:

> listid=1
>       Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stafflease\index.php on line 563
>       statusid=

Comment: you should check if it's set before doing that `for` loop.

Comment: Put `echo` _after_ checking whether or not `$_POST[$i]` is set.

Comment: if (isset($_POST[$id]) && !empty($_POST)). you can check whether $_POST[$i] exists

Comment: it still doesnt work. the lines with $_POST[$i] are the ones not working

Comment: Try and put quotes '$i' around the I!

Answer (score 2):

You are not iterating safely on your `$_POST`.
the error says **"undefined offset 1"** means that `$_POST[1]` doesn't exists

you should iterate safely using foreach, that guarantees you have the key (offset)

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $listid = $key;
    $statusid = $value;
}
```

if you still want to use range 1 to 27
you should ask isset **Before** going to that cell.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 27; $i){
    if(!isset($_POST[$i])) continue;
    //here it is safe to use $_POST[$i]
}
```

Comment: `<label>Dynamic URL's</label> 
   <select>
    <option name="20" value="1">Ok</option>
    <option name="20" value="2">Information</option>
    <option name="20" value="3">Warning</option>
    <option name="20" value="4">Danger</option>
   </select>

   <label>Too long URL's</label> 
   <select>
    <option name="21" value="1">Ok</option>
    <option name="21" value="2">Information</option>
    <option name="21" value="3">Warning</option>
    <option name="21" value="4">Danger</option>
   </select>` these are the reason why i need to use the range 1-27

Answer (score 0):

its not appropriate to get values from $_POST array with the help of integer indexes in side a loop. You can use foreach loop.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    $listid = $key;
    $statusid = $value;
}
```

$key here will be the name attribue of your html form fields.
It also better to see what is inside $_POST array, for that purpose you can do for testing purpose.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
die;
```

Comment: i cant use foreach because i still have a couple of input type inside my form beside the dropdowns

Comment: ok no problem, then try var_dump() thing, and get values from $_POST array via exact indexes..